# Creating survey webpart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part

I want to add survey webpart to a page

I tried creating a survey (add an app- Survey), added a survey with options and added that list webpart to the page

But it's showing all the survey questions

I want to display the page that comes when **respond to survey** is clicked inside the webpart

Also on submitting response it should show the percentage of votes

Is it possible out of the box in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: You can use the survey list form if it helps you

Comment: can i have the URL of newitem for that list in an iframe?

Comment: you can have hyperlink and redirect to that form to the user having permission.

Comment: ah okay
but I want that to be displayed in same page inside the webpart itself
is that possible?

Comment: You can try adding the form in a div tag but not sure of adding as an webpart

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add Survey List form to div can go to the Page and edit in designer
 and select the Insert tab from the ribbon -> New Item Form -> select "CUSTOM LIST FORM..." (not one of the pre-populated lists or you will get the barebones default content type!) -> Choose the list for the form you want to show and the content type, click OK -> Save the page in SP Designer.